# responsive/fluid diamond grid

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

How could I make this responsive or fluid using percentages? So that I dont have to give it a fixed pixel width

Example - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kiveg

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'><span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="" /></span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="" /></span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="" /></span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="" /></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
    background: none;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 137px;
    height: 137px;
}

a {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 3px solid #cbccce;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
}

li span {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -25px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Based on:
http://viget.com/inspire/who-says-the-web-is-just-for-squares

Answer (score 1):

I actually created a jQuery plugin for this.

Demo: http://mqchen.github.io/jquery.diamonds.js/
Github: https://github.com/mqchen/jquery.diamonds.js

Answer (score 0):

You'd need bigger images, but essentially every width is related to it's parents width.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJeik

```
ul {
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
}
li {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box'
  background: none;     
  float:left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}
a {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 3px solid #cbccce;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 25px auto;
        position: relative;
    }
        li span {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
        }
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to make it so that the diamonds dont overlap?

Comment: Well technically speaking they don't overlap, but since they're rotated you'll have to do some extra work.